# Apache won't start in VirtualBox

Tags: apache, virtualbox

I'm running VirtualBox with a Windows XP SP 2 system (my native OS is Windows XP, too). I tried to install XAMPP, WAMP or EasyPHP but with all of them Apache won't start.

XAMPP says that port 80 is busy, but I'm not running any program since the VM is empty and I've just installed the OS and Firefox. I tried to edit the httpd.conf file anyway, setting another port but it gives me the same error.

I tried to start Apache manually by executing the httpd.conf file and I get an error like

> Unable to start the application. The application configuration is not correct. Removing and installing the application again may solve the problem.

(I'm using Windows XP in another language so I don't know the exact error message in English)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Run `netstat -a | find "80"`and post output

Comment: Is your VM connected to a network, i.e. can you browse to some site?

Comment: Are you starting it as an administrative user? What about if you try installing it as a service and running it with the system user? What kind of network are you using Bridged,NAT or ? Is Windows Firewall enabled or disabled?

Comment: Yeah, my VM is connected and I'm typing this right now. Installing it as a service resulted in the same error. Windows Firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message you posted is related to MSVCRT libraries.
This is due to manifest information inside httpd.exe or underlaying DLLs.

You need to install correct version of MSVCRT redistributable runtime on your virtual machine.

Which exact version of apache you are running? Or better say, provide download link, I can check version of MSVCRT lib for you.

Try this for fisrt or nay previous version if not succeeded :http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I tried installing the package you suggested but it still gives me the same error. The download links are these:
XAMPP http://www.apachefriends.org/it/xampp-windows.html#4584
EasyPHP: http://www.easyphp.org/save-easyphp-539.php
the error is the same with both.

Comment: If I can suggest best apache with stable PHP stack for you, try ZendServer CE.I installed about 20 times on vary environments , vary OS and every time works like a charm.It's free, just register for free.Here is link : http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/