# Unable to start Apache in XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

I have downloaded `xampp-win32-1.7.7-usb-lite.7z` and unzip it to `C` drive in my VirtualBox. Then i tried to start `Apache` through `xampp-control.exe`. when i press Start button in-front of `Apache` label, `apache started port 80` display in text area in that window. but nothing happen. Start button not change to stop. but mysql is start properly. how could i start Apache ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try ZendServer CE, it works great in a Virtual Box. Apache gives problem inside a Virtual Box.

You can also refer this post: [Apache won't start in VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327745/apache-wont-start-in-virtualbox)

Answer (score 0):

Try to **Restart Xampp** from the option **Explore**

> > Xampp Contorl-> Explore-> Xampp-Restart

If you have other service installed like **.NET SQL Server** it may block xampp

> > Xampp Contorl-> SCM -> SQL server-> Manual from Automatic
> >
> > > Xampp Control-> SCM-> Web client->Disabled

If you like to run service always **Check SVC** for both **Apache Mysql** It will ask you to install service click **YES** to install

> > Finally Restart your machine

Answer (score 0):

i don't know whether your issue is resolved or not,if not please try the below mentioned cases

1.if your Skype account is logged in,please log out from that(usuall skype uses default Ports numbers 80 and 443 )

2.check whether any other application is running on the port 80,if so please change that port number to other.to see that from a command prompt, run netstat -a. This will output a list of ports that are currently running.
(how to change the default port number is open your httpd.conf file and search for localhost you  will find 80 there and change that to your desired number)

i think these are the main cases so please go through this cases also..